# How to access version property from BOM with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, lombok, annotation-processing

I'm migrating a small multi-module project from Maven to Gradle, to evaluate and (hopefully) to learn something.

```
subprojects {
    group = "com.company.project-name"

    apply plugin: "java"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.2")
        compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
        annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. Despite a small problem it's already working. As you can see, I'm importing `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies` as platform dependency / BOM (Bill of Materials). As far as I understand this is equivalent to a Maven parent. `spring-boot-dependencies` already defines almost everything I'm using in this project. However, I'm also using Lombok. Luckily Spring takes care of that too.

This work as expected for the `compileOnly` dependency `org.projectlombok:lombok`. The problem is the `annotationProcessor`. Compiling the project results in an error:

```
[...]
Execution failed for task [...].
> Could not resolve all files for configuration [...].
   > Could not find org.projectlombok:lombok:.
     Required by:
         project [...]
[...]
```

If I change it to something like this:

```
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20")
```

... it works. But I want Gradle to use the version definition for Lombok from `spring-boot-dependencies`, because I don't want to define it again myself. With Maven I could just use the Maven property `lombok.version`. So I also tried something like this:

```
annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok.version}")
```

Unfortunately, this result in another error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project [...].
> Could not get unknown property 'lombok' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

What is the Gradle equivalent to access a defined version property from a platform dependency / BOM?

Comment: Old question but I am encountering that and I would love to know if someone have a solution for this!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
annotationProcessor platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.2")
```

Make sure the annotationProcessor is on the top of the dependencies.

```
    dependencies {
        annotationProcessor platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.2")
        annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

        implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.2")
        compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok") 
    }
```